# How to build for Qualcom Snapdragon 800 msm8974 chip on Samsung Note 3

Tags: android, makefile, arm, embedded-linux, rom

Hi I have been working on compiling an android image for my Samsung Note 3. Basically I downloaded the source from Samsung, which directed me to download a version of Android Open Source Project code.  I then followed the procedures in the readme files provided. But there are some discrepancies between the procedures and tools to be used from Samsung vs. Qualcomm's documents. My question is about finding the right procedure, and get a working image. I have followed the Samsung's procedures, and they have not resulted in a working image as of now. I tried to flash the boot.img file I created, and collected the recovery logs which are posted [here](http://pastebin.com/vpxedp8e) I could be doing something wrong though; I am not saying the procedures are wrong. So here are the issues I am struggling with:

1- Samsung's readme file says to download arm-eabi-4.7, while Qualcomm says to used 4.8 with their compiler add on llvm. As of now, I plan to try llvm with 4.7 and 4.8 and see what happens. I have already tried 4.7 w/o llvm and it has not helped.

2 Samsung procedures state to update the CROSS_COMPILE statement with the path to above arm-eaby-4.7 executable, export ARCH=arm, then create a config file with the following statement:

```
make VARIANT_DEFCONFIG=msm8974_sec_hlte_spr_defconfig msm8974_sec_defconfig SELINUX_DEFCONFIG=selinux_
defconfig
```

and then run make. While Qualcomm's llvm readme file states to issue the following command:

```
ndk-build NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=snapdragonclang3.6 APP_ABI="armeabi-v7a"
-C <some_project>
```

I know I have to have a path to ndk-build script and I know where it is. What I do not know is

1- If Samsung's procedures run ndk-build also. I looked through the Makefile in the project's root directory and do not see any reference to it. Would the arm-eabi-4.7 run ndk-build perhaps?

2- What is the best way to get to a working image for me? I do not see the NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION and APP_ABI variables in the Samsung's .config file. Can I set these as environment variables?

3- Samsung's procedures state to set an environment variable of ARCH=arm, while Qualcomm's configuration passed to the ndk-build is armeabi-v7a

4- Qualcomm's procedure calls for a project name. Is this something generic or would I find it somewhere in Samsung's files? I did a search in the .config and Makefile and did not see any reference to it.

5- Are there any tags I should add to this post to get the attention of right folks who know and deal with questions like mine stated above?

@jww - Thanks. I'll try the procedure, and I am going through the material you shared. I hope I can have my other questions above addressed also.

Update - Hey I noticed I did not get any reply about actual issue. Another question I wanted to ask is if it helps to build an image, which provides more information about what is wrong with my image? Do I do that via the config command?

Comment: Related, be sure to change the four platform keys. See, for example, [How to replace the release keys in the AOSP](http://vanuitert.org/wordpress/platform/how-to-replace-the-test-keys-in-the-aosp/). Marko Gargenta has a really good treatment of platform security at [Android Security Underpinnings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NS46492qyJ8). Nikolay Elenkov also discusses them at [Code signing in Android's security model](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2013/05/code-signing-in-androids-security-model.html).

Comment: I want to thank you for sharing this info. It was *very* important to my goal.